# PHP selection of drop down menu not storing in variable

Tags: php, html

I have a simple table with staff names stored in the column f_operator_name.
I have a drop down menu in a php form with these staff names available for selection. Here is a snippet of the relevant the code:

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Operator: <select name=f_operator_id></h2>";
$sql="SELECT * FROM radio_archive_index_gui.t_operator ORDER BY f_operator_id";
$result = pg_query($connection, $sql);
if (!$result){
    die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
}


while ($arr = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
    $operator_id=$arr['f_operator_id'];
    $operator=$arr['f_operator_name'];
    echo "<option value='$operator'>$operator</option>";
}

echo "</select>";


##### submit form to carry out echo statement for testing purposes


echo "<ul>
<th><input type='submit' name='new' value='Confirm Information'/></th>
</form>
</ul>";

if (isset($_POST['new']))
{
    echo $_POST['operator'];
}
?>
```

When someone selects the staff name I want it to be stored in a variable. I'm testing the submit form at the bottom which is intended to print out the name that has been selected ( in the variable operator), but it's not printing anything out. Can anyone see any issues?

EDIT *** Here's the updated code after some advice from Barmar with the variable information also, for some reason the echo statement still isn't working:

```
<?php


$connection = pg_connect("host=10.100.51.42 port=5432 dbname=reportingdb user=rai_gui password=password");

echo "<h2>Operator:</h2> <select name='f_operator_id'>";


$sql="SELECT * FROM radio_archive_index_gui.t_operator ORDER BY f_operator_id";


$result = pg_query($connection, $sql);


if (!$result){
    die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
}


while ($arr = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){

    $operator_id=$arr['f_operator_id'];

    $operator=$arr['f_operator_name'];

    echo "<option value='$operator'>$operator</option>";
}

echo "</select>";


##### submit form to carry out echo statement for testing purposes


echo "<ul>
<th><input type='submit' name='new' value='Confirm Information'/></th>
</form>
</ul>";

if (isset($_POST['new']))
{
    echo $_POST['f_operator_id'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `<select>` inside `<h2>` and then put the `<option>`s and `</select>` outside it. HTML elements have to be nested properly, and `<option>` has to be inside `<select>`.

Change it to:

```
echo "<h2>Operator:</h2> <select name='f_operator_id'>";
```

And the index in `$_POST` has to match the name of the `<select>`, so `$_POST['operator']` should be `$_POST['f_operator_id']`.

Comment: Ok, thanks I've changed that in my script, but the info from the selection is still not being stored in the variable, I must have done something else wrong.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but this still doesn't work. The names of the staff are populated in the drop down, so there is definitely a connection to the database, but nothing is echo'd when I hit the 'Confirm Information' button.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the HTML to make sure the form is constructed correctly.

Comment: Where is the `<form>` tag?

Comment: Your HTML seems to be really messed up. You have `<th>` inside `<ul>`, but it needs to be inside `<tr>`, and that needs to be inside `<table>`. You have `</form>` inside `<ul>`, and no `<form>`.